# Moving Android SDK to another folder with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to move Android SDK from default folder (C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk) to another drive. I already changed the following items in VS options to new path:

- Tools | Options | Xamarin | Android SDK Location
- Tools | Options | Cross Platform | C++ | Android | Android SDK

However, for some reason, Visual Studio still tries to run ADB from the old location. Where can I configure the new one?

---

**Edit:** ProcMon log

```
08:34:09,2974468    devenv.exe  9548    CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe   PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
08:34:09,2975321    devenv.exe  9548    CreateFile  C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe.exe   PATH NOT FOUND  Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

> Open Registry Editor by selecting Run from the Start buttons context
>   menu, typing regedit in the dialog box, and choosing OK. Navigate to
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools in the
>   folder tree on the left. Modify the Path registry variable to match
>   the path to your Android SDK.

From: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You may have environment variable set.

Please check by typing the `SET ANDROID` in a command window.

If so, you can change it from your environment variables.