# Issue deploying after having moved the Android SDK in VS2015 Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have found a similar question already asked, and the solution did help somewhat, but the problem still persists: ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33820901/moving-android-sdk-to-another-folder-with-xamarin) one).

So, what actually happened: I wanted to move the SDK to C:\ instead of AppData to make it accessible to other users, changed the path in Visual Studio Tools>Options>Xamarin>Android SDK and changed the Path variable, however Visual Studio couldn't find the files (even on the original profile) when I re-ran it(the API 23 android.jar in particular).
 This was fixed by changing the registry entry, as described in the previously mentioned question. VS now displays

```
[I:Unknown]:              Found Android SDK. API levels: 10, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23
```

on project load.

However, when I try to deploy the project (onto a currently running and functioning emulated Android Virtual Device, no less,)  this error message gets displayed:

```
Could not find android.jar for API Level 23.
This means the Android SDK    platform for API Level 23 is not installed. 
Either install it in the Android SDK Manager (Tools > Open Android SDK Manager...),
or change your Xamarin.Android project to target an API version that is installed. 
(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\MonoForAndroid\AndroidSDK\platforms\
android-23\android.jar missing.)
```

It's still looking for the SDK in the old AppData folder. Which system/environment variable, registry entry, or Visual Studio Setting do I change to fix this? Thank you very much in advance for any answer, and apologies for possible duplicity, it's the fifth hour I've been on this and my head would really prefer to sleep.